# What are set theoretic properties?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As far as I know in every category the properties are the ones which are invariant under the isomorphisms in that category (e.g. connectedness in the category of topological spaces). Now, I'm wondering what are the properties in the category of sets, i.e. the invariants under the isomorphism in the simple category of sets (of course beside the cardinality of sets which is clearly a set theoric property). In other words, is the cardinality of sets the only set theoric property?

Comment: Cardinality is all there is.

Comment: Thanks. Crystal Clear.

Comment: Now, I was studying Joshi's topology book the other day and it said that "Every set theoric property is automatically a topological invariant". I assume this means that the cardinality and other set theoric properties of the underlying sets of topological spaces is the same whenever the spaces are homeomorphic. Have I got it right?

Comment: And, of course, properties *derived* from cardinality, such as: being (non)empty, being (in)finite, being (un)countable etc.

Comment: Since homeomorphisms are bijections, it's trivial that they preserve set theoretic things like cardinality.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila I get it. But in the case of topological spaces I don't think it is that trivial since we are dealing with bijections on the power set of the underlying set and not with the bijections on the underlying set itself.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Well, I'm still an undergraduate student very new to topology. Maybe I should think more about the basic concepts to digest them better. Thanks for your help.